# Show that two summations are equivalent

Tags: probability

> Show that
>   $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i - \bar{x}\right) \left(y_i - \bar{y}\right)
> = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i\right) - n \bar{x} \bar{y}.
> $$

My work is attached:

[image: photograph of work].

I'm stuck on what I should do next. 
Any guidance in the right direction would be great!

Comment: Is not $\sum_i x_i\bar{y}=n\bar{x}\bar{y}?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Recall that by definition $\overline{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ and  $\overline{y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i$.
Therefore by linearity,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{y}x_i=\overline{y}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=n\overline{x}\overline{y},\quad
\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{x}y_i=\overline{x}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i=n\overline{x}\overline{y},\quad
\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{x}\overline{y}=\overline{x}\overline{y}\sum_{i=1}^n 1=n\overline{x}\overline{y}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes, got it!! Thanks so much-- I didn't make that connection. Makes complete sense now!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
Use $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \bar{x} y_i = \bar{x} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  y_i = n \bar{x} \bar{y}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \bar{y} x_i = n \bar{x} \bar{y}$.

Answer (score 0):

[step wise Solution of this question in following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7egZv.jpg)

Comment: Please type your answers using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) rather than posting an image.  Images cannot be searched.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion , actually I did not know about that.